# Eclipse RCP to define a new kind of Project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I want to definite a new kind of project which is a bundle with *.X file, i named it as "X project". How to do it?

firstly, extends a Project class(eclipse.xxxx.internal.Project), but i remembered the resources which in "internal" package; i also saw the org.eclipse.core.resources.Iproject, is there a subclass of it could be used for my case?

so , how to do it? please show me a example. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a **Project Nature**.

There is already a sample project of the type you want in eclipse-

1. Goto New -> Plugin Project
2. Give name and click next
3. [image: Create a project from an existing template]

This will give you a sample template for to play with. You can understand the patterns there.

More information can be found here -

http://jawher.net/2009/09/26/howto-create-a-new-project-nature-in-eclipse/